# Mac OS X : how to check if tclsh is installed and, if not, install it?

Tags: macos, shell, tcl

I need to write a script which checks if tclsh is installed on Mac OS if not install it.

In this case it is tclsh but generally the applications can be random.

I'm checking if the package (tclsh) is installed or not using pkgutil --pkgs command. But this does not show tclsh in the returned list (although tclsh is available in system).

So how do I check if the tclsh is installed on system from command line and install it in case it is not installed.

Comment: tclsh can be installed via several ,mechanisms that do not use pkgutil e.g. compile from source. Macports, fink etc. What do you want in that case?

Comment: How do you plan to run the installer?  How do you plan to obtain a package to install?  Do you plan to ask permission before installing it?  Isn't tclsh installed by default, anyway?

Comment: the script should ask for permission if they are required. The things is how to detect if tclsh is installed on mac os or not ?

Comment: The method of installing the required package is only using installer.

Comment: FWIW, OSX always has a copy of tclsh and wish around; they've been distributed with it for a good few years (it was there in Tiger IIRC) and hardly anyone uses very old OSX any more. *However*, the version might not be what you want and it might not have the libraries you want.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you'd run `type -a tclsh`.  You might also try `locate tclsh`.

However, if you're distributing a Tcl program, you might want to investigate building a [Starkit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3661) -- a self contained, one-file application. See [Build Your First Starkit](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10558)

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you want a fully self-contained one-file Tcl application, it should be a [Starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663).

Comment: You don't need to build a starpack on OSX; applications there are really directories, not files, and you can have a whole Tcl/Tk runtime inside no problem. (It helps that Tcl's not really all that big by comparison with many libraries.)